# Weblogic12c setup + Spring JMSTemplate +Tibco EMS

Tags: weblogic12c, spring-jms, tibco, tibco-ems

I'm new to JMS/TIBCO EMS and weblogic setup.

I'm able to post the message to TIBCO EMS by using old way and new way. I would like to setup the configuration in Weblogic 12c and remove the username, pwd ,server URL and queue name (hardcoded values).

Below is the code for old way; which I was able to send a message to the queue.

```
private void tibcoEMSQueueSender() throws NamingException{
        try {
            ConnectionFactory myConnFactory;
            Queue queue;
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Hashtable env = getEnvProps();
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

            myConnFactory = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(Constants.JNDI_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            queue = (javax.jms.Queue) ctx.lookup(Constants.TIBCO_QUEUE_NAME);

            Connection connection = myConnFactory.createConnection(Constants.USER_NAME, Constants.PASSWORD);
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
            textMessage.setText("Hello EMS");
            messageProducer.send(textMessage);
            connection.start();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private Hashtable getEnvProps(){
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", Constants.PASSWORD);
        env.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory");
        env.put("java.naming.security.principal", Constants.USER_NAME);
        env.put("java.naming.provider.url", Constants.SERVER_URL);
        return env;
    }
```

New way using Spring JMS Template.
Spring version: 4.1.6
I have created an XML free project with latest Spring and Hibernate.
So, I was using @EnableJms for configuration.

In JMSConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan({ "com.xxx.xxx" })
@PropertySource("classpath:local_application.properties")
public class JMSConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();

        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory");
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url",Constants.SERVER_URL); 
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal",Constants.USER_NAME); 
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials",Constants.PASSWORD); 
        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(jndiProps);
        return jndiTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter authenticate() throws JMSException, NamingException {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(); 

        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(Constants.USER_NAME);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(Constants.PASSWORD);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }

    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws NamingException, JMSException{
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
         Context ctx = null;
         Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
         env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", Constants.PASSWORD);
         env.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory");
         env.put("java.naming.security.principal", Constants.USER_NAME);
         env.put("java.naming.provider.url", Constants.SERVER_URL);
         ctx = new InitialContext(env);

         connectionFactory = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(Constants.JNDI_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
         connectionFactory.createConnection(Constants.USER_NAME, Constants.PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean jmsQueueName() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();

        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(Constants.TIBCO_QUEUE_NAME); 
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException, NamingException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(authenticate());
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination((Destination) jmsQueueName().getObject());

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSender queueMessageSender() {     
        return  new MessageSender();
    }

}
```

I'm autowiring the MessageSender class in controller and able to send the message to Tibco queue. In the above java code I want to eliminate all the hard coded values and write them to weblogic12c server configuration(like creating a foreign server with tibco url, creating a JNDI and a queue.

Question on above code:

1. I had to create a connection in jmsConnectionFactory(). Is this necessary? Should I also open and close the connection/session ? Usually, when this(setting up JNDI, queue and connection factory) part is moved to weblogic configuration, I need not create a connection; correct?
2. Is this a standard practice?

I was thinking, if I had the foreign server setup properly with tibco tcp:://xxxxxxxxxxx:7222, username and pwd I should be able to establish a communication channel with tibco server and post the message to the queue. The connection factory name should be a match I guess.

Can you help me find an article on this or share your experience step by step? Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a foreign server to avoid hardcoded passwords in code.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jms_modules/foreign_servers/ConfigureForeignServers.html) is the guide which I followed to create a foreign server in WLS.

Create a module.

setup a remote Connection Factory.
setup remote queue.
setup Initial context and pass the credential and principal.

Use the local names in Spring JMS template to establish connection and send messages.

This is for TCP.